# MS Access query: between two numbers

Tags: sql, ms-access

This isn't as simple as it sounds. I have a scenario where I enter a number into a text field into a form, then I want to press a button to search for a number CLOSE (or exact) to that number. If i leave this field blank i want it to return all results.

I am (very) new to SQL and Access so I'm having a bit of trouble. I know how to find an exact value:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtFuelConsumption] & "*"
```

(My textbox is called txtFuelConsumption)

An example of what I want returned:

Say I type in the number "10" into the textbox and then run the query. I want it to show me all data entries with a fuel consumption rate of 7 to 13.

I tried using the between function, but could not wrap my head around it.

Thankyou!

Edit: Just thought of another approach i could take. I could create a standalone combo box with the values "small, medium, large" and use a query to assign specific values to 'small, medium and large'. Although, again, I do not know how to do this. I've just put it here as a suggestion in case people can't figure out my first problem.

Edit:

```
    SELECT [Car Table].Car_VIN, [Car Table].Car_Class, [Car Table].Car_BodyType,
[Car Table].Car_Colour, [Car Table].Car_Make, [Car Table].Car_Model, [Car
Table].Car_EngineType, [Car Table].Car_TransmissionType, [Car
Table].Car_GPSAvailability, [Car Table].Car_BootSpace, [Car
Table].Car_FuelConsumptRate, [Car Table].Car_SeatNumber, [Car
Table].Car_GreenStarRating, [Car Table].Car_ANCAPSafetyRating, [Car
Table].Car_DriveType
FROM [Car Table]

       WHERE ((([Car Table].Car_VIN) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]!
    [NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtVIN] & "*") AND (([Car Table].Car_Class) Like "*"
    & [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbClass] & "*") AND
    (([Car Table].Car_DriveType) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]!
    [NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbDriveType] & "*") AND (([Car Table].Car_BodyType)
    Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbBodyType] &
    "*") AND (([Car Table].Car_Colour) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbBodyType] & "*") AND (([Car Table].Car_Make)
    Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtMake] & "*")
    AND (([Car Table].Car_Model) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtModel] & "*") AND (([Car Table].Car_EngineType)
    Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbEngineType]
    & "*") AND (([Car Table].Car_TransmissionType) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation
    Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbTransmissionType] & "*") AND (([Car
    Table].Car_GPSAvailability) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![ChGPSAvailability] & "*") AND (([Car
     Table].Car_SeatNumber) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtSeatNumber] & "*") AND (([Car
     Table].Car_GreenStarRating) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbGreenStarRating] & "*") AND (([Car
     Table].Car_ANCAPSafetyRating) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbANCAPSafetyRating] & "*") AND
     ((Abs([car_fuelconsumptrate]-Nz([Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform]
    .[Form]![txtFuelConsumption],[car_fuelconsumptrate]))<=Nz([2],9999)) AND
 ((Abs([car_bootspace]-Nz([Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]
![txtBootSpace], [car_BootSpace]))<=Nz([100],9999)));
```

syntax error edit:

```
 AND ((Abs([car_fuelconsumptrate]-Nz([Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtFuelConsumption],[car_fuelconsumptrate]))<=Nz([2],9999))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your current expression will not find a single value, it will also find 100.

For a range, use a method like this:

```
Select
    *,
    Abs([ConsumptionRate]-[Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtFuelConsumption]) As ConsumptionRange
From
    [Car table]
Where
    Abs([ConsumptionRate]-Nz([Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtFuelConsumption],[ConsumptionRate])) <= Nz([InputDeviation], 9999)
Order By
    Abs([ConsumptionRate]-[Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtFuelConsumption]) Asc
```

Comment: From what i know of SQL, doesn't start with SELECT and the FROM..? I'm just a bit confused. Also, I am unsure how to filter for deviation; or what 'Asc' does. I'm sorry, I'm legitimately really new to SQL and Access. I've put my existing code in as an edit so you see the gist of what I'm doing. Just to clarify, I want this feature to be part of a much bigger search function (not to mention that when the field is left blank, I want all results returned). Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `From`. And `Where` included to show possible filtering.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm doing this right; I used the code above (filling in with my own variables) and when i run it i get a textbox asking me to enter the parameter value. Also, why is the line "Abs([car_fuelconsumptrate] - [Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].Form![txtfuelconsumption])" in the select method? I'm also unsure as to why you did Order By. I'll update my code above and edit it so it's easier to read

Comment: Another point, in the select method, for the part that says "as consumptionrange", why isn't that used anywhere else? Also, i should mention that my field name for fuel consumption is Car_FuelConsumptRate.

Comment: Of course, adjust field names to the actual names. You can leave out the Abs... expression from the `Select` statement and leave out the `Order By` if you don't want to view the deviation sorted in ascending order. Asking for a parameter value indicates a misspelled field name.

Comment: Thankyou so much! I've almost got it working aside from two small things. Firstly, the "<=3" in the code, does that mean that the answer can deviate by three in either direction? Secondly, if I typed nothing into the field, I want all the results to be shown, however, nothing is shown here. How would i go about doing that? Just incase my wording is confusing here is a simpler layout of what I'm trying to say: 

IF field is null THEN
return all results.

When i say 'all results' i mean just don't take fuel consumption into account because i want the other parameters to work too. Thanks!

Comment: I've modified the code to allow to input the requested deviation. `InputDeviation` can replaced with a field from your form as for `txtFuelConsumption`. If `InputDeviation` is empty (Null), all deviations will be allowed. Also, if no `txtFuelConsumption` is input, all values will be listed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that input deviation can be replaced with a field form my form; could i just make the deviation an integer? Also, i ran into a syntax error that i think stems from what i said above, i edited my post to include it. Thanks again and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Deviation was an integer, though fixed. I thought you would let the user input it. If not, leave it at the fixed value of 3.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when i try to save the code; I'll update whats above and i'll also create a small extract of the problem area so you can easily check

Comment: I tried playing around with it for a good while and after researching i can't figure out how the nz function works, maybe i made a mistake in that part.. or maybe it's a simple bracket mistake, but i tried changing the brackets around. Edit: umm... haha... yeah it was a bracket mistake. everything seems to work now! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The VBA proposal:

Consider your field name is `[FuelConsumptionRate]`.

```
Private Sub btn_Click()
  ' Check whether no value is typed
  myValue = txtFuelConsumption.Value
  If(IsNull(myValue)) Then
     Me.Filter = ""   ' Clear the filter
  Else
     ' Set a new filter with values calculated
     ' Me represents the Form object
     Me.Filter = "(([FuelConsumptionRate] < " & (myValue*1.1) & ") And (" _
             "([FuelConsumptionRate] > " & (myValue*0.9) & "))" 
  End If
  ' Do requery, so the new filter is applied 
  Me.Requery
End Sub
```

The values `0.9` and `1.1` represent `10%` margin of your value. You can change them for example to apply a combobox value.